# WSO2 esb cluster synchronization updated exception

Tags: wso2, synchronous, updating, wso2-esb

i have 3 WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 clustered: 1 manager and 2 workers.

Till now all was going on well and synchronization suing SVN forwarded to the workers every changes in manager's artifacts.

Now i'm facing up to an issue: every time i change an artifact on the manager... while trying the updating the workes lanch this exception:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-06-17 16:20:22,110] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.FilterMediatorFactory} -  Invalid attribute values for source and/or regex specified {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.FilterMediatorFactory}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-06-17 16:20:22,110] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.sequences.SequenceDeploymentInterceptor} -  Sequence Deployment from the file : /usr/local/wso2esb-worker/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/documentaleWorkerSequence.xml : Failed. {org.wso2.carbon.sequences.SequenceDeploymentInterceptor}
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Invalid attribute values for source and/or regex specified
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.handleException(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.FilterMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(FilterMediatorFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getObjectFromOMNode(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:253)
    at org.apache.synapse.registry.AbstractRegistry.getResource(AbstractRegistry.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.getSequence(SynapseConfiguration.java:505)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:300)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.init(AbstractListMediator.java:127)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:289)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeployer.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.SequenceDeploymentInterceptor.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeploymentInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-06-17 16:20:22,111] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer} -  Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /usr/local/wso2esb-worker/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/documentaleWorkerSequence.xml : Failed! {org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer}
org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Sequence Deployment from the file : /usr/local/wso2esb-worker/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/documentaleWorkerSequence.xml : Failed.
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:473)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeployer.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.sequences.SequenceDeploymentInterceptor.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeploymentInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Invalid attribute values for source and/or regex specified
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.handleException(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.FilterMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(FilterMediatorFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getObjectFromOMNode(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:253)
    at org.apache.synapse.registry.AbstractRegistry.getResource(AbstractRegistry.java:155)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.getSequence(SynapseConfiguration.java:505)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:300)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.init(AbstractListMediator.java:127)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.init(SequenceMediator.java:289)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.SequenceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(SequenceDeployer.java:64)
... 19 more
```

what's happened?

Comment: Would you post the contents of the "documentaleWorkerSequence.xml"?  I'm curious since the caused by exception reads `Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Invalid attribute values for source and/or regex specified` and it looks like you are using a filter mediator which could throw this.

Comment: i catched an attribute xmlns="" in a sequence imported byt the DocumentoSequence.xml